# Iterating through array are not give proper result

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
var links_length = links.length;

for (var i = 0; i < links_length; i++)
{
    if (links[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('test') !== -1)
    {
        //blabla
        // but now I want to target for example... HREF attribute of link that got test in it's rel attribute... so

        if (links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('test2') !== -1)
        {
            //blabla2

            // but it doesn't work
            // it won't give me href with test2 of the link with rel attribute with test. The code give my last link with href of test2... dunno why. Any ideas?
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't get proper link with `rel='test'` and `href='test2'` ? The `href` attribute iteration should target only the links with `rel='test'`, right?

HTML:

```
<a href="test2" rel="test">Proper Test</a> // I want to grab this one
<a href="testing" rel="testing">Test</a>
<a href="testing" rel="testing">Test</a>
<a href="test2" rel="besting">Test</a>
<a href="testing" rel="test">Test</a>
```

Comment: `links` variable holding `length`, `links_length` is not declared. Could you please check your code again?

Comment: please share the html

Comment: done, it could be any html with links, just source view something on the net.

Comment: There's a typo in your for loop. It should be `links.length` instead of `links_length`.

Comment: for loop with links_length should work just fine cause links_length = links.length

Comment: @innertest You never provided the above information in your question. You're only showing one variable: `links`.

Comment: Are you actually using a tagname of "link" or is it a?

Comment: The code works, all you need to do is provide link elements with a tag name of "link". (or change 'link' to 'a' to seach for anchor elements) Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your comments, I assume you are stuck with javascript closure. By this loop is simple enough, you just need to break where you got the conditions satisfied.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
var mylink = '';

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    if (links[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('test') !== -1)
    {
       if (links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('test2') !== -1)
        {
            mylink = links[i];
            break; //If you need the first one. else create an array and keep pushing the ietms.
        }
    }
}

console.log(mylink);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="test" href="www.test2.com">
<link rel="test1"  href="www.test2.com">
<link rel="test2"  href="www.test2.com">
<link rel="test3"  href="www.test2.com">
```

Comment: thank you, I need to look closer at closures I guess.

Comment: @innertest not for this you don't. Closures are related to function calls. The actual answer is that you used the wrong tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a few js errors and made assumptions about the html. Just do some step by step troubleshooting using console.log, alert, or the console debugger and you'll catch that stuff.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'test') {

    if (links[i].getAttribute('href') == 'test2') {

      console.log("link index:" + i );

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="test2" rel="test">Test</a>
<a href="best" rel="testing">Test</a>
<a href="thetest2" rel="testing">Test</a>
<a href="test2" rel="besting">Test</a>
<a href="thetest2" rel="testing">Test</a>
```

Comment: thanks, added html, I want to grab ONLY one (first). I thought that first IF will grab only those with Attribute('rel').indexOf('test'), and second if only those with Attribute('href').indexOf('test2') - so "there can be only one" wih test/test2... do I make wrong assumptions?

Comment: IndexOf means that the word text is contained within the text your searching. Looks like you actually want to compare the whole string.

Comment: My answer has been edited to work by comparing the entire string so your test cases should work as expected.